# How can I schedule restart of my network connection?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, router, scheduled-tasks

I schedule my PC to turn on an hour before I arrive work so that it can run tasks while I'm on my way. However, one time, there was a task which needs internet connection but unknowingly, the wifi connection on my computer has an error and i arrived with a pending task. I usually turn on/off the modem/router (physically since its web interface doesn't have this functionality). Only then will it restart and the wifi connection is then fixed.

My question is... is there a way that I can just SCHEDULE to restart the connection of my wifi internet in my PC (thus restarting my network connection)? Or will this just get fixed once the computer has restarted?

Comment: my first thought is that this will cause more failures than it prevents, just by virtue of all the things that can go wrong when joining a network. it would be much better to attempt to detect the downed connection and restart it only if needed. is there an event log entry associated with the internet connection failure?

Comment: Technically you can use the task scheduler to trigger a task based on something in the eventmanager (e.g. on connection lost). That script could do something like sleep 60 seconds and ipconfig /renew. However getting this correctly means building in some sanity checks. That might be the hard part.

Now as a programmer I think this is a nice challenge. But unless it happens quite often you will spend more time in building and testing this than you gain from it.

Answer (score 0):

NIC Configurator 2018 can schedule NIC resets on multiple computers and its pretty easy to do.  However, this is not a free product.  Check the Youtube video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yg_lpF63KMc or google NIC Configurator.

Answer (score 0):

If restarting y`our router fixes the problem, you can always get an [outlet timer](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=outlet%20timer) and plug the router into it.  Then schedule it to power off and on.  This will resolve the symptom, but not fix the underlying problem.  However, it till work...